# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UIInput'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I have problem converting type String to UI Input in Unity3D. I want to retrieve the information from database and place them in a textbox (UI Input)

This is the error message. (1st error)

> "Cannot convert method group 
>   `ToString' to non-delegate type`UIInput'. Consider using parentheses to invoke the method"

```
password = GameObject.Find ("tb_password").GetComponent <UIInput> ().ToString;
```

Comment: Right now, I am confused on how to convert type string to UI Input. My error shows "cannot implicitly convert 'type' string to 'UIInput'.

Comment: You need to show us your code where you have the error so that we can help you.

Comment: My codes are as follow. 'username = DB.getName(LoginSystem.userNameStatic); password = DB.getPassword ("password");'

Comment: I am sorry, I am new in asking questions here, if I am doing it wrong, please tell me so. Thanks alot, really need your help for my ques :)

Comment: Please update your question above and put in all relevant code there. Don't put it in the comments.

Comment: Also, what are the types of `username` and `password`? Are they strings or textboxes?

Comment: I just changed my question and added the relevant codes.

Comment: Does your `GetComponent<UIInput>()` method returns a `string` or a `UIInput`?

Comment: It returns a UI Input.

Comment: Then obviously you can't assign a `UIInput` to a `string` variable. If `UIInput` is a textbox, you can get its `Text` property to assign to the variable instead: `username = ...GetComponent<UIInput>().Text;`

Comment: By the way, what type does `getName()` and `getPassword()` return?

Comment: After changing it to text, the error shows that Type `UIInput' does not contain a definition for `Text' and no extension method `Text' of type `UIInput' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: That means your `UIInput` is not a `TextBox`. It's probably a user control or a custom control. Try to find a property or method in the `UIInput` class that returns what you need (eg. username as a `string`).

Comment: getName() and getPassword() returns the username and password fields!

Comment: No, I mean what _type_ are they? For example, Are they `string`?

Comment: Actually, can you post the whole error message(s) above? Also include which line(s) the errors are pointing to. That should help us a lot in diagnosing where the error comes from.

Comment: Show us please. Show us the code where you state that they are strings. The errors you get seem to be suggesting they are not.

Comment: Posted the 1st error above. Thanks!

Comment: I posted the 1st error and the line of codes that has the error and the error msg.

Comment: Oh geez. You're simply not calling `ToString()` correctly there. You're missing the `()`, which the error tells you. *"Consider using parentheses to invoke the method"* Then again, that whole line is rather nonsensical and will more than likely not do what you think it does.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste the brackets as well!

Comment: And now, all my errors are back to "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UIInput'.

Comment: Then your `password` is not of the string type. It's a `UIInput`, as we have said before.

Comment: How do you think I can solve my errors?

Comment: By leaving out the `ToString()` call. And then you can get your text from the UIInput by doing something like `password.text;`. See also the documentation: http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_input.html

Comment: My errors are cleared. I am still unsure on the password.text, could you explain it to me? Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to override the label with a string value, which results in type mismatch and actually is not what you've intended. You have to access `UIInput` property `value` or `defaultValue` if you wan't to provide defaults for user - anyway according to your code you probably don't want it.

Anyway, if you are using the latest NGUI, you should correct your code like this:

```
UIInput username = GameObject.Find ("tb_username").GetComponent <UIInput> ();
UIInput password = GameObject.Find ("tb_password").GetComponent <UIInput> ();

if( username != null )
    username.value = DB.getName(LoginSystem.userNameStatic);
if( password != null )
    password.value = DB.getPassword ("password");
```

That should work if you correctly find objects with these names you specify, otherwise it won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks alot! Still working on it. I just changed my question, hope it helps better!

Comment: Updated my answer according to your question.

Comment: Hi, I just tried your codes out and my information did not appear in the UI Input aka textboxes. Any information (codes) you need from me to derive more answers? Thanks alot

Comment: I have specified the objects with the correct names as well. But it has no error.

Comment: Have you attached a `UILabel` to `UIInput` `label` property? If you did you can also try to force the update, like `username.UpdateLabel()`.

Comment: According to the question, `username` and `password` are strings. But in your answer, they are something else?

Comment: @SF Lee: No, according to the question and to the error message (`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UIInput'`) `username` and `passwords` are `UIInput` type, and the error is probably on last two lines. If they were strings, the error message would be the other way round: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'UIInput' to 'string'.

Anyway, the types obviously should be specified in the question and the're not, which leads to misunderstanding.

Comment: @SFLee if you get your errors on the last two lines of your code, then username is by no means a string. `username = GameObject.Find ("tb_username").GetComponent <UIInput> ();` tells us it isn't.

Comment: Well, the question did say: _The username and password are both type String._ Maybe the error comes from `GameObject.Find(...)` where the it's expecting a `UIInput` parameter?

Comment: But if they would be `string` wouldn't the error message from the title be the other way round? Maybe the asker should clarify that things once again.

Comment: I agree. The whole code looks like there are more than 1 errors to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the UILabel component under the NGUI's input widget instead of the UIInput component at the root of the input widget and set the text in the label (UILabel.text = "my text"). You could also make a function that updates the label text and pass the text as a parameter for this function. Call the function when you want to update the text.